# How to do a "element by element in-place inverse" with pytorch?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pytorch

Given is an array `a`:

```
a = np.arange(1, 11, dtype = 'float32')
```

With numpy, I can do the following:

```
np.divide(1.0, a, out = a)
```

Resulting in:

```
array([1.        , 0.5       , 0.33333334, 0.25      , 0.2       ,
       0.16666667, 0.14285715, 0.125     , 0.11111111, 0.1       ],
      dtype=float32)
```

Assuming that `a` is instead a pytorch tensor, the following operation **fails**:

```
torch.div(1.0, a, out = a)
```

The first parameter of `div` is expected to be a tensor of matching length/shape.

If I substitute `1.0` with an array `b` filled with ones, its length equal to the length of `a`, it works. The downside is that I have to allocate memory for `b`. I can also do something like `a = 1.0 / a` which will yet again allocate extra (temporary) memory.

How can I do this operation efficiently "in-place" (without the allocation of extra memory), ideally with broadcasting?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pytorch follows the convention of using `_` for in-place operations.
for eg

```
add -> add_  # in-place equivalent
div -> div_  # in-place equivalent
etc
```

Element-by-element inplace inverse.

```
>>> a = torch.arange(1, 11, dtype=torch.float32) 
>>> a.pow_(-1) 
>>> a
>>> tensor([1.0000, 0.5000, 0.3333, 0.2500, 0.2000, 0.1667, 0.1429, 0.1250, 0.1111, 0.1000])
```

---

```
>>> a = torch.arange(1, 11, dtype=torch.float32) 
>>> a.div_(a ** a) 
>>> a
>>> tensor([1.0000, 0.5000, 0.3333, 0.2500, 0.2000, 0.1667, 0.1429, 0.1250, 0.1111, 0.1000])
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. The in-place-methods come in very handy. One question though: While I understand that `x^-1` equals `1/x`, I am missing a way to apply broadcasting. If I had a scalar `b` instead of a `1`, I had to do a "division" AND a multiplication, i.e. `x.pow_(-1); x.mul_(b)`. This seems rather odd to me ...

Comment: Yes, it does seem a bit odd doing `x.pow_(-1).mul_(b)`. `torch.div` accepts a `(tensor, scalar)` or `(tensor, tensor)` for now and not `(scalar, tensor)` which would have made it a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks again - I though I had overlooked something.